# How can we get bounding box results from VNRecognizedTextObservation after we filter compactMap results

Tags: swift, vision

I have this code to get observation of recognized texts.

```
  guard let observations =
                    request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation] else {
                return
            }
```

To get top candidates

```
let recognized = observations.compactMap { observation in
                return observation.topCandidates(1).first
            }
```

And to get recognized text with high confidence

```
  let confidenceL = recognized.filter{$0.confidence > 0.3}
```

Now I want to draw something around recognized higher confidence text but
I can only could get coordinates from observation like this

```
    observations[k].topRight
```

and confidenceL array different from observations as we can guess so how can I find which observations contain confidenceL[k] text.

Answer (score 0):

Well

```
    let recognized = observations.compactMap { observation in
            return observation.topCandidates(1).first
        }
```

and

```
      guard let observations =
                request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation] else {
            return
        }
```

arrays sizes are matching so I just gave up using

```
    let confidenceL = recognized.filter{$0.confidence > 0.3}
```

with tears and did something like this

```
    for k in 0..< recognized.count {
       if recognized[k].confidence > 0.3 {
         // Doing drawing things here
       }
    }
```